# Is it possible to display formula result in cell instead of cell value?

Tags: excel, formatting

Now I know it isn't possible to enter a number in a cell and have a formula run and replace that number because then the formula would have to run again on the previous result and so on...

What I am looking for is not changing the value of the cell, but displaying the result of the formula using the value of the cell. The question might as well be how to use a formula as custom cell formatting, if that is even possible.

Basically, what I want to do is enter the number of seconds in a cell, and have that cell be displayed as hours in decimal format. for exacmple, if I enter 12000 in a cell, the formatting should display the cell as 3,33h. The same as the formula =12000/3600 would result in, just without using the formula in another cell. I don't want to change the value from 12000. I figure it should be possible since formatting can be used to interpret a number as a date, displaying hours, minutes and seconds for example. I just could not figure out how to tell it to ignore the date part and just interpret the number as seconds.

I would also be happy with something like 3h 20m 00s for example.

Comment: This would require the formatting to do math, it does not do that.  You best bet is vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: But even then I doubt you can format the cell without doing the math and changing the underlying value.

Comment: But doesn't formatting already do math? if I use the time format, it converts the number from an integer to a date and it has to do math to do that, no?

Comment: no it does not do math.  Dates to Excel are Doubles.  It is the number of days since 12/31/1899.  With time being the decimal portion of a full day.  It only formats that number.   It is the same as any other format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by VBA not by Formatting

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Target.Cells
            If c.Column = 1 Then
                If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                    c.Value = SecToStr(CLng(c.Value))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Function SecToStr(v As Long) As String
    Const Mnt As Integer = 60
    Const Hor As Integer = 3600 '60*60
    Const Dys As Long = 86400   '60*60*24
    Dim tmp As Long
    If v >= Dys Then
        tmp = v Mod Dys
        v = (v - tmp) / Dys
        SecToStr = v & "d "
        v = tmp
    End If
    If v >= Hor Then
        tmp = v Mod Hor
        v = (v - tmp) / Hor
        SecToStr = SecToStr & v & "h "
        v = tmp
    End If
    If v >= Mnt Then
        tmp = v Mod Mnt
        v = (v - tmp) / Mnt
        SecToStr = SecToStr & v & "m "
        v = tmp
    End If
    SecToStr = SecToStr & v & "s"
End Function
```

change any cell in col `A`

Comment: But this changes the value, the op stated: `I don't want to change the value from 12000` They want the underlying value to stay `12000` but format it `3.33h`.  This code changes the underlying value to a text.

Comment: This can not be done because letters(s,m,h,d,...etc)are preserved for the formatter

Comment: It can't be done at all how the OP wants it.  but you can escape the letters by using `\` in front of them.